# Non-persistent data in Django - allowing potential users to test applications

Tags: database, django

I'd like to allow potential users to 'log in' with a fake account to try out my application. Everything created while logged in with this fake account will be deleted after they close the browser window. What would be the best way to do this? Just deleting everything after the user has logged out? How will I know if the user closes the browser window? Any tips or suggestions would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this great and simple app, that solved all of my needs:

https://github.com/danfairs/django-lazysignup